# how to display a long list of data in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollview

Im in need of some control that allows to scroll through large amount of data. It is basically a help page, so i jus need to display lot of textblocks and images.

I tried using the listbox but it does not give the desired effest. I tried placing the textblocks into the each listitem, but the texblocks needed to the resized to that the complete text is shown. Finally the texblocks came out of the screen area!!

Scroll viewer allows me to add only one text block

Could someone tell me how to go about it? Is it the right way? Or is there any other control which allows me to do the same? What does a longlistselector do?

Alfah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `LongListSelector` which would be an overkill in this case. You should stick with `ListBox` control as it provides automatic [Virtualization](http://blog.landdolphin.net/?p=78).

To layout the `ListBoxItems` nicely, try setting margins to your `ListBoxItem` (or this can be done in a ListBoxItem style) and applying styles to your `TextBlock`.

[image]

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBoxItem Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your description I cannot say if you can't fix your requirements with the standard controls, for that you need to post the XAML you have right now.

About the LongListSelector there is a very nice two part article about this control on WindowsPhoneGeek.com:

Part 1: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Part2: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios

The first post should give you a good overview if this control is right for your requirements. Please note that there is a new version of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) on codeplex which fixes some issues with the long list selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scroll viewer available with the GRID and can add as many texts you want example mantioned below:

```
<Grid Name="ansGrid" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="3" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="261"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="195*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Race Category" FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Start Time" FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="any" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="thing" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="etc" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="etc" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a help page, many times I've found it easiest to just embed an HTML page in your project and use the WebBrowser control to display it. For an example, see this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811(v=VS.92).aspx

If you want to avoid HTML you can also try the new (though still poorly documented) RichTextBox:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx